# Coda Popup Bubbles problem on parent div overflow is scroll?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list of online users containing only names. I am using [Coda Popup Bubbles](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-popup-bubbles/) to show more details on mouse over of an online user's name. It shows a popup containing the user's details.

I have added `overflow:auto` and a fixed height to the list `div`, so that it will scroll in the case of a large number of online users. This user list is loaded dynamically using an ajax request.

Now the problem is, for first 2-3 users (or for users at top of list) the popup is not displaying correctly. It only displays partially - the list's top border is like a boundary for the popup and the popup above the border is not displaying. I noticed that if I remove `overflow:auto` then it works perfectly.

No issue regarding `z-index`.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a screen shot.

Comment: Link to the page and/or edit your question to include code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get any good solution on this, so finally I changed popup plugin.

I used [this](http://maxvergelli.wordpress.com/jquery-bubble-popup/).